# Gradient clipping in pytorch has no effect (Gradient exploding still happens)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I have an exploding gradient problem when train the minibatch for 150-200 epochs with batch size = 256 and there’s about 30-60 minibatch (This depends on my specific config). But I have an exploding gradient issues even if I add the code below.
[image]
As you can see this below images, notice that in step about 40k there’s the swing of gradients between ± 20k, 40k and 60k respectively. I don’t know why this happens because i use the clip_grad_value_ above. Also Using the learning rate decay from 0.01 to about 0.008 at step 40k.
[image]
Or do I need to update the weight parameters by myself something like this
image
But i think optimizer.step() should do the job and the clip_grad_value_ is an inplace operation so i don’t need to take the return value from function. Please correct if i did anything wrong. Thank you very much

Best regards,
Mint

Comment: Can you try using torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_ ? Unless pt is just what you named torch in which case nevermind

Comment: I don't see a reason why the gradient clipping wouldn't work, it seems to work fine for the other iterations. Even if you manage to get it working, your results won't be good, simply because the gradients are way too high for the model to learn properly. You should probably revisit your loss or model output to bring them to a reasonable magnitude. It looks to me like you're trying to output values in the hundreds, try to normalise them to values between [0, 1], which are more appropriate for a model. That wasn't your question, but I believe the solution to your gradient problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @Mike I think it's will not help by changing the pt to torch. Thank you for your answer

Comment: @MichaelJungo Yes I think for other iteration it work fine but in some cases it shouldn't goes like 40k or sometimes 1e+70 something like this. The loss function is just the MSE loss + weighted BCELoss(Class imbalance problem). Also the loss start from like 400 and end up around 0.4-0.6. I also perform a learning rate decay over time shouldn't change the gradient too much like this. So it's not make sense in my opinion to have the gradient value like 40k or 1e+70 in the middle of training when loss and learning rate so small.

Comment: @MichaelJungo  My task is a regression task by using the RNN architecture. Since it's a batch and RNN stuff with padding. I have no idea to normalise it (Will find some ways). But normalise will affect the loss landscape and help too. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks right, but try using a smaller value for the clip-value argument. [Here's the documentation on the clip_grad_value_() function you're using](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/utils/clip_grad.html#clip_grad_value_), which shows that each individual term in the gradient is set such that its magnitude does not exceed the clip value.

You have clip value set to 100, so if you have 100 parameters then `abs(gradient).sum()` can be as large as 10,000 (100*100).